# Nginx + uWSGI on a fresh Ubuntu install - bind error port 80

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, port, wsgi, uwsgi

I know this is a common problem usually having to do with apache or another service already running on port 80 and I have done a lot of searching and running netstat and still have not figured out why I am getting this error.

I rebuilt my slice, did a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 and setup nginx + uwsgi. It worked and I was able to see my Django site. I then installed Postgres8.4 and the rest of the stack needed for Geodjango from [this link](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install).

After that was done I tried to restart nginx and I get this error:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg]: still could not bind()
```

I have nginx set to listen 80. Here's an output from `netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep 80`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Output from `sudo lsof +M -i4`:

```
nginx    2330     root    8u  IPv4   3195      0t0  TCP *:www (LISTEN)
nginx    2331 www-data    8u  IPv4   3195      0t0  TCP *:www (LISTEN)
uwsgi    2335        s    4u  IPv4   3259      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
uwsgi    2352        s    4u  IPv4   3259      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
uwsgi    2353        s    4u  IPv4   3259      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
uwsgi    2354        s    4u  IPv4   3259      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
uwsgi    2355        s    4u  IPv4   3259      0t0  TCP localhost:8000 (LISTEN)
```

Anyone have any other ideas how I can figure out what is blocking port 80?

**edit**

Paste of my /etc/init.d/nginx script here: http://dpaste.com/hold/400937/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you have issued `restart` as an argument to your init script?

I would expect

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

to complain if nginx was already running. Which it sounds like it was.

Comment: you are correct. Once I got fuser installed it is showing 2 nginx running on port 80 with PID 2381 and 2382. When I kill them with fuser I am able to restart once without the bind error and then it comes up again. I set worker_processes 1; I edited my post above and pasted the /etc/init.d/nginx script I am using. Maybe the problem is there?

Comment: @knuckfubuck if you just want nginx to pick up changes you made to nginx conf files (like you added new site) do **reload**

Answer (score 1):

`fuser -n tcp 80` will show you a PID of process using port 80.

Comment: I get fuser "command not found". sudo fuser gives the same result.

Comment: You should install it using this: `apt-get install psmisc`

Answer (score 1):

netstat -plan

will provide you the process name then use killall -9

and restart you nginx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you paste your actual config files from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.. Also you might try to be more explicit about the IP addresses you are binding to.

Recently I have experienced strangeness with nginx (8.54) and uWsgi (.96) on Ubuntu 10.10 KVM node servers. I employed non local address binding combined with VLAN/bonding 802.3ad and bridging so the setup is similar in theory to a "slice" from your provider. My hunch was that it was related to nginx, although the underlying layers in Ubuntu have been going through tremendous changes as well ..

I would suggest being as explicit as possible when configuring nginx. Especially in an environment with multiple IP's or aliased IP addresses on an a single interface.

http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-nonlocal-bind.html