# Nginx Using KiB of shared memory for push module in

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, phusion-passenger, ruby

I'm setup nginx with passenger on a ubuntu 14.04
and the nginx is throwing

> 403 Forbidden error

I checked the permissions and it is all ok.
I checked the nginx conf and it seems ok

```
user root;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.24;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name ;
        root /home/ubuntu/site/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
       index index.html;

        access_log  logs/access.log;

        location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }


       error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
       client_max_body_size 4G;
       keepalive_timeout 10;



            }
}
```

but the nginx log keeps showing:

> 2016/02/18 03:28:57 [info] 13605#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory
>   for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:42 2016/02/18 03:31:11 [info]
>   13642#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:42

Is someone having the same problem?

Comment: The log also says 'info' (meaning the application isn't regarding this as a warning or an error).  Reading the [official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/push_stream/#push-stream-shared-memory-size) it says 32MB is the default.  What leads you to think this is a problem?  I doubt this has anything to do with your 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Can be related to https://serverfault.com/questions/308176/nginx-cant-bind-to-port-80-nothing-running-on-port-80